# organizing if statements in for loops to pull specific data from a string

Tags: python, if-statement, data-structures

I have the following

```
items=' g energy 4"3/4 drilling jar'
print(items.split())
if 'energy' or 'ge' in items.split():
    print('E')
if 'slb' or 'schlumberger' in items.split():
    print('S')
if 'oes' or 'overseas' in items.split():
    print('O')

output 
E
S
O
```

what I want is to check if any of the words are in the string but what i am getting is that it tells me all the words are in the string i want to check the word not the characters of the word how can I go around to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: I am not sure I tried to prevent that by using split however when i remove the or from the if statement it works perfectly then but with or it just matches every string and says any word is in that string even if its not

Answer (score 1):

your understanding of or is not quite correct.

If we take one of you `if` line: `if 'slb' or 'schlumberger' in items.split()` and use print to evaluate its truthness

```
#you are essentially saying this
print(bool('slb'))
#or this
print(bool('schlumberger' in items.split()))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
False
```

So you can see `'slb'` will return true and `'schlumberger' in items.split()` returns false.

As you are using an `or` then anything to the left of the `or` will be evaluated first. Since `'slb'` returns true the `or` will not check the other side and will just say that this `if` is true and print your letter.

instead you need to check each string in items seperated with an `or`.

```
items=' g energy 4"3/4 drilling jar'.split()
print(items)
if 'energy' in  items or 'ge' in items:
    print('E')
if 'slb' in items or 'schlumberger' in items:
    print('S')
if 'oes' in items or 'overseas' in items:
    print('O')
```